# Usage and meaning of 'up front'

Tags: phrase-usage

When should I use the phrase "up front"? Can anyone explain giving some examples?

Comment: This is the kind of question where you should really try to find the information yourself, as it is [readily available](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/up-front), and [readily findable](https://www.google.com/#q=%22meaning%20of%20up%20front%22&nfpr=1&ei=SclrUdHLAYXc2AWLuoCYDw&sqi=2&start=0&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.45175338,d.b2I&fp=d77acb0f8cf43ae5&biw=1388&bih=875). Then, if you're still confused, tell us what you've discovered so far, and explain why you're still confused, and the community will be glad to help you out.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In a financial context, it means paying before goods or services are provided. More generally, to be *up front* means not to hide anything in your dealings with others.

Here are some examples of usage:

> The minister for the Department of Health was **up-front** about his previous role as a director of a private hospital.
>
> The car costs $10,000 total over three years, but with a $2,000 **up-front** deposit.
>
> We had an **up-front** and frank discussion about how we thought the contract was going. It was nice to hear some open and honest views for a change.
>
> I'm going to be **up-front** with you. The business is doing badly, and we're going to have to lay-off two thirds of the staff.

Comment: Can you give examples of its usages?

Comment: Have you tried Google?

Comment: I have googled it but get confused as at some places it shows 'upfront' means 'in advance', is it so?

Comment: Could be. It can have a number of meanings depending on the context.

Comment: @SanjeevRai: I've added some examples of usage to Barrie's excellent answer.

Comment: Matt♦ Thanks. That gives a good idea of the possibilities.